# Positioning of divs in center and right and left for any browser(cross-browser)

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular6

```
Three div panels:-
1) (div-B) one div with max-width = 500px and min-width=400px should always on 
    the center of all browsers.
2) (div-A) one div should show and hide on the left of (div-B) having min-width 
   = 200px and max-width= 300px;
3) (div-C) one div should show and hide on the right of (div-B) having min-width 
   = 200px and max-width= 300px;
```

The show and Hide of div-A and div-C should be in such a way it should not move div-B from its position, however, it can attain its max-width and min-width available. div-B should always be in center of all browsers.

### Layout of page:-

```
Header
<--Left button here                                       right button here-->
to open div-A panel                                       to open div-c panel
(basically a dropdown)                                  (basically a dropdown)


         Left Panel <---20px---> Center Panel <---20px---> Right Panel   
         (div-A)                  (div-B)                     (div-C)    

1) (div-A && div-B), (div-B && div-C) having margin 20px in between always.
   div-A should grow towards left and div-c should grow towards right relative to div-B(min-width and 
   max-width availability).
2) div-B should not move to right or left when div-A and div-C should hide. 
 But div-B should grow towards its left or right keeping div-B fixed to 
  center of browser window and tries to achieve its max-width(keeping center 
 axis fixed) if space available towards right or left.
```

```
<header>
//show hide button for div-A
<div class="div-A-button">Dropdown button A</div>
//show hide button for div-C
<div class="div-C-button">Dropdown button C</div>
</header>

<main>
<div class="panel div-A">Panel A </div>  //show and hide using div-A-button
<div class="panel div-B">Panel B </div>  //fixed always show
<div class="panel div-C">Panel C </div>  //show and hide using div-C-button
</main>
```

Here is stackblitz link:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpj35u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: What do you mean with "all browsers"? There are many different possible approaches to solve your problem, but without the information which browser you want to support, nobody can give a good answer. :)

Comment: It means cross-browser/ any-browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS grid. I think I've understood your layout. Let me know if the example below is right.

```css
main {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 300px) minmax(400px, 500px) minmax(200px, 300px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

main>div {
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

.div-B {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="panel div-A">Panel A </div>
  <div class="panel div-B">Panel B </div>
  <div class="panel div-C">Panel C </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using `flex`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      .container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          flex: 1;
          overflow: hidden;
      }

      .classA {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          min-width: 200px;
          max-width: 300px;
          height: 200px;
          width: 300px;
          background-color: red;
      }
      .classB {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          flex: 1;
          min-width: 400px;
          max-width: 500px;
          width: 500px;
          height: 200px;
          margin-left: 20px;
          margin-right: 20px;
          background-color: yellow;
      } 
      .classC {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          min-width: 200px;
          max-width: 300px;
          height: 200px;
          width: 300px;
          background-color: blue;
      } 
      </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="classA">A</div>
    <div class="classB">B</div>
    <div class="classC">C</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as far as I understood your Problem the container `div-B` should always be centered, regardless from `div-A` odr `div-B`. I change two major things:

1. I updated the styles to flexbox which has a very good browser support so far.
2. Changed the hide class from `display:block` to `visibility:hidden`, so the free space is still blocked to `div-B`
3. For better visual understanding I added a red border to the `.panel` container

> Checkout the example in fullscreen, to see that `.div-B` is flexible

```js
$(".pull-left").click(function() {
  $(".div-A").toggleClass("hide")
});

$(".pull-right").click(function() {
  $(".div-C").toggleClass("hide")
});
```

```css
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

header {
  height: 40px;
}

div.pull-left {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.pull-right {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.row .panel {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}

.row .panel.div-B {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello> -->
<header>
  <div class="pull-left" (click)='showHide("A")'>button-div-A</div>
  <div class="pull-right" (click)='showHide("C")'>button-div-C</div>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel div-A">Panel A </div>
    <div class="panel div-B">Panel B</div>
    <div class="panel div-C">Panel C </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS Grid and define the `grid-column` property to all possible cases, using utility classes on the parent element. Center the `main`, not the `div`s.
This snippet below should works, the code syntax is a bit different from Node.js version. See full page.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showA = false;
    $scope.showB = false;
    $scope.showHide = function(val) {
      if(val === 'A'){
        this.showA = !this.showA;
      }
      else if(val === 'C'){
        this.showC = !this.showC;
      }
    };
});
```

```css
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
div.panel.show{
  display: block;
}

div.panel.hide{
    display: none;
}
header{
  height:40px;
}
div.pull-left{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
    display: block;
    color: red;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}

div.pull-right{
  float:right;
  width:100px;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
main{
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}
div.row{
  width:100%;
  float: left;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 300px) minmax(400px, 500px) minmax(200px, 300px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.div-A {
  display: none;
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  background-color: blue;
}
.div-B {
  display: block;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  background-color: red;
}
.div-C {
  display: none;
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.showA .div-A {
  display: block;
}
.showA .div-B {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}
.showC .div-B {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
.showA.showC .div-B {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
}
.div-C {
  display: none;
}
.showC .div-C {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello> -->
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<header>
<div class="pull-left" ng-click="showHide('A')">button-div-A</div>
<div class="pull-right" ng-click="showHide('C')">button-div-C</div>
</header>

<main>
<div class="row" ng-class="{'showA': showA, 'showC': showC }">
  <div class="panel div-A">Panel A </div>  
  <div class="panel div-B">Panel B </div>  
  <div class="panel div-C">Panel C </div>
</div>
</main>
</div>
```

### Possible solution

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4jdpca - change colors as You want.

## References

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the width using The `minmax()` CSS function and to hide a div such that centre div remains in center of page use `visibility : hidden` property of css this will only hide it from page but will keep it in DOM and so the center div will not be affected if either of two divs on side gets hide on click

[working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjjp4r)

```
<div id="container">
    <div (click)="visibility = !visibility" [ngClass]="{'hide' : visibility}">
     <select style="width :-webkit-fill-available;"></select>
      at most 300 pixels
    </div>
    <div>20px</div> //separator
    <div>
    <div style="position:absolute">
      Item with 400 to max 500px width
    </div>
  </div>
    <div>20px</div>    //separator
    <div  (click)="visibility1 = !visibility1" [ngClass]="{'hide' : visibility}">
        at most 300 pixels.
    </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 300px) 20px minmax(400px, 500px) 20px minmax(200px, 300px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
  width: 100%;
}

#container > div {
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
  border: 1px dotted red;
 }
 .hide {
   visibility: hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple way of your request, please check the snippet below. Hopefully it is as you were requesting.

```js
var divchecker = 0;

$('.pull-left').click(function() {
    //you are hiding the Div A now
    divchecker = divchecker+1;
    $('.div-A').hide();
    $('.pull-left2').show();
    $('.pull-left').hide();
    $('.gridsection').css('grid-template-columns', '70% auto');
    if (divchecker == 2){
      $('.gridsection').css('grid-template-columns', '100%');
    }
});
$('.pull-right').click(function() {
    //you are hiding the Div C now
    divchecker = divchecker+1;
    $('.div-C').hide();
    $('.pull-right2').show();
    $('.pull-right').hide();
    $('.gridsection').css('grid-template-columns', 'auto 70%');
    if (divchecker == 2){
      $('.gridsection').css('grid-template-columns', '100%');
    }
});

$('.pull-left2').click(function() {
    //you are showing the Div A now
    divchecker = divchecker-1;
    $('.div-A').show();
    $('.pull-left2').hide();
    $('.pull-left').show();
    $('.gridsection').css('grid-template-columns', 'auto 60% auto');
    if (divchecker == 2){
      $('.gridsection').css('grid-template-columns', '100%');
    }
});
$('.pull-right2').click(function() {
    //you are showing the Div C now
    divchecker = divchecker-1;
    $('.div-C').show();
    $('.pull-right2').hide();
    $('.pull-right').show();
    $('.gridsection').css('grid-template-columns', 'auto 60% auto');
    if (divchecker == 2){
      $('.gridsection').css('grid-template-columns', '100%');
    }
});
```

```css
main {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 60% auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

main>div {
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

header{
  height:40px;
}
div.pull-left,div.pull-left2{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
    display: block;
    color: red;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background-color:yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

div.pull-right,div.pull-right2{
  float:right;
  width:100px;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background-color:yellow;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="pull-left">Hide-div-A</div>
  <div class="pull-left2" style="display:none;">Show-div-A</div>
  <div class="pull-right">Hide-div-C</div>
  <div class="pull-right2" style="display:none;">Show-div-C</div>
</header>

<main class="gridsection">
  <div class="panel div-A">Panel A</div>
  <div class="panel div-B">Panel B</div>
  <div class="panel div-C">Panel C</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks. It is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you hear about [Bootstrap Framework](https://getbootstrap.com/). I let you here an example of how i will do a responsive (cross-browser) layout for your requirements with this framework. The only requirement i can't strictly match is next one:

> Three div panels: **1) (div-B)** one div with max-width = 500px and min-width=400px should always on the center of all browsers. **2) (div-A)** one div should show and hide on the left of (div-B) having min-width = 200px and max-width= 300px; **3) (div-C)** one div should show and hide on the right of (div-B) having min-width = 200px and max-width= 300px;

The column grid system of **Bootstrap** (it divide the screen width on 12 columns) auto-manage the width of the columns for make the site responsive to various types of screen, so I don't know if will be posible to matchs your max/min pixels widths values, but you can assign a percentage of the total columns to the three elements you have for similar approach. The rest is all good. You can check next example. I hope this helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#btnToggleA").click(function()
    {
        $(".div-A").slideToggle();
    });
    
    $("#btnToggleC").click(function()
    {
        $(".div-C").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.margin-20px
{
    margin: 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Wrapper for the Boostrap layout -->
<div class="container-fluid">

<header class="row">
  <div class="col-12 p-0">
    <button id="btnToggleA" class="float-left btn btn-sm btn-primary">Toogle Div-A</button>
    <button id="btnToggleC" class="float-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">Toogle Div-C</button>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- Class "mt-3" just adds some margin-top for good looking but can be removed -->
<!-- Classes "bg-*" adds background colors, not needed but helps to visualize elements -->

<main class="row mt-3">

  <div class="col-3 text-center p-0">
    <div class="div-A bg-info">Panel A</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 text-center p-0">
    <div class="div-B bg-warning margin-20px">
      Panel B
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3 text-center p-0">
    <div class="div-C bg-info">
      Panel C
    </div>
  </div>

</main>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't center an element in `<div>` using `relative` positioning, since so, you're setting up your UI to arrange each element next to the previous. Therefore, I'll end up in using `absbolute` positioning (use `fixed`, instead, if you want those elements not to scroll).

1. To align an element to the left:

   ```
   #element {
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
   }
   ```
2. To align an element to the center:

   ```
   #element {
       position: absolute;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translateX(-50%);
   }
   ```
3. To align an element to the right:

   ```
   #element {
       position: absolute;
       right: 0;
   }
   ```

To center elements, I came up with a strange but working solution: I place the element's `left` on the center of the parent (by setting up `left: 50%`) and I translate the element horizontally of its half width (`transform: translateX(-50%)`). Notice that this is actually working since percentages are relative to the parent in any property but `trasform`, where they're relative to the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good answers here for how to do the CSS yourself, but complex framing stylesheets are annoying to maintain. Consider using a framework.

[**Skeleton**](http://getskeleton.com/) would be my first choice for your use case.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getskeleton.com/dist/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getskeleton.com/dist/css/skeleton.css">
<!-- .u-pull-* will float content left/right -->
<button class="u-pull-left">Button A</button>
<button class="u-pull-right">Button C</button>
<!-- .container is a centered responsive wrapper -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="four columns">Panel A</div>
    <div class="four columns">Panel B</div>
    <div class="four columns">Panel C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy with flex..

```
.parentDiv{
    display: flex;
}
.childDiv{
    margin: auto;
}
```